# Disable caching in open-uri

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I have to, sadly, poll an endpoint and update another system when the data changes. I wrote a loop (with a `sleep` statement so I don’t DOS the server):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

desired_data = 'foo'
data = nil
url = nil

while data != desired_data do
  sleep(2)
  url = "https://elections.wi.gov/index.php/elections-voting/statistics"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(url))

  puts doc

  # do some nokogiri stuff to extract the information I want.

  # store information to `data` variable.
end

# if control is here it means the data changed
```

This works fine except when the server updates, `open(url)` still returns the old content (even if I restart the script).

It seems like there may be some caching at play. How do I disable it?

Here are the HTTP headers returned:

````
HTTP/2 200
date: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 14:00:44 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=dd8fca84d468814dd199dfc08d45c98831601647244; expires=Sun, 01-Nov-20 14:00:44 GMT; path=/; domain=.elections.wi.gov; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
x-powered-by: PHP/7.2.24
cache-control: max-age=3600, public
x-drupal-dynamic-cache: MISS
link: <https://elections.wi.gov/index.php/elections-voting/statistics>; rel="canonical"
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge
content-language: en
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
last-modified: Fri, 02 Oct 2020 12:47:38 GMT
vary: Cookie
x-generator: Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)
x-drupal-cache: HIT
x-speed-cache: HIT
x-speed-cache-key: /index.php/elections-voting/statistics
x-nocache: Cache
x-this-proto: https
x-server-name: elections.wi.gov
access-control-allow-origin: *
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 058b368b9f00002ff234177200000001
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 5dbef38c3b6a2ff2-ORD```

If it matters, I’m using Ruby 2.7 on macOS Big Sur.
````

Comment: How can you know that the server has updated content if you're receiving cached content? You can ask the server not to use its cache but it doesn't have to respect your request, and in this case it does not respect cache headers in the request. More at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control and https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html. In this case, something like `open(url, 'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache') { |f| p f.meta }` still receives cached content.

Comment: When I reload the same endpoint in a web browser I see new content.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem on the Drupal 8 website itself as it has its own cache manager - and it seems like there's a cache per user somewhere if you have new content using a web browser.

> It is easy to see which cache contexts a certain page varies by and which cache tags it is invalidated by: one must only look at the X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts and X-Drupal-Cache-Tags headers!

But those headers are not available in your list. If you're in touch with the website's developers ask them to do the following:

> You can debug cacheable responses (responses that implement this interface, which may be cached by Page Cache or Dynamic Page Cache) by setting the http.response.debug_cacheability_headers container parameter to true, in your services.yml. Followed by a container rebuild, which is necessary when changing a container parameter.
>
> That will cause Drupal to send X-Drupal-Cache-Tags, X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts headers.